# CSS height with percentages instead of pixels

Tags: html, css, height, percentage

I'm currently working on a website with a responsive design (well i'm trying to).
I have been coding HTML and CSS for quite a long time but i'm not familiar with the use of percentages for the height and width.

The design of my website is very simple, it's actually a personnal website for my cv, portfolio etc. It's just a one page website.

The design looks like this

[image]

In each block of color there is a background image fitting between the white lines with text in it.

My problem is : i've never used percentages before (I want my website to be responsive).

So i've done my blocks but in CSS i'm stucked for the height.

But the image doesn't appear, it has no height! Can you please help me, i've tried using min-height etc. but i never get what I want.

Thanks a lot!

The css :

```
body
{
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#page
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: Myriad Pro, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: white;
}

.wrapper-intro
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 500px;
}

#intro
{
    background: url(images/space.png);
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

The html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>Site</title>
</head>

<body>
      <div id="page">
        <div class="wrapper-intro">
            <section id="intro">
                <header>
                Title
                </header>   

                <nav>

                </nav>
            </section>
        </div>
      </div>

        <section id="about">
            <article>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="portfolio">
            <article>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="cv">
            <article>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="contact">
            <article>
            </article>
        </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember when you use % with css, the parent container needs to have a set height/width. What you're doing right is saying that you wanted #intro to have 100% of the height of nothing - which is still nothing (because the parent element doesn't have a height) . Have your main container, or even body, take up a height and width of 100% and you should be good.

try this for intro

```
#intro
{
    background: url(images/space.png);
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Alright check this code out. I think it's closer to what you're looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Site</title>
<style>

html, body
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

#page
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: Myriad Pro, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 32%;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#intro, #about, #portfolio
{
    background: url(http://cdn.sneakhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/960x500_51-30_gunmetal.jpg);
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
      <div id="page">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section id="intro">
                <header>
                Intro
                </header>   

                <nav>

                </nav>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section id="about">
                <header>
                About
                </header>   

                <nav>

                </nav>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section id="portfolio">
                <header>
                Portfolio
                </header>   

                <nav>

                </nav>
            </section>
        </div>
      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh ok. So my image has a 500px height and "intro" is in a wrapper. 
So I've put the height of the wrapper to 500px and intro to 100%. The image now appears but when I change my window's size it doesn't get smaller and that's what I actually want. Can you help me? Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Can you paste a link or show more of your code? Also too you usually want to avoid using heights when you can with css. Try playing around with setting the width of the image instead of the height. That should make it fluid.

Comment: I've edited my topic with my code! About the height: but when i don't put a height my background image doesn't appear :/ My html looks like quite empty right now, i just started but i'm stucked with this block with no height thing!

Comment: if you want your background to resize you need to set background-size too http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp, "background-size: 100% 100%;"

Comment: Ok so i did that (background-size: 100% 100%;) on #intro and my wrapper has a height of 500px. But now when change I change my window's size, only the width resize, the height stays at 500px all the time. It deforms the image. I've tried putting no height to the wrapper but then my #intro (the image) is only like 10px tall (again, with only the width changing when I change my window's size). Could you help me? I feel like the solution is near, I've tried several things but nothing works properly... It's crazy how this percentage thing is not intuitive! haha thanks a lot!

Comment: Can someone help me? I'm going a bit crazy with this! haha Nothing works!

Comment: Anyway you can post all of your code? It should be a simple fix and I don't mind helping.

Comment: Thanks Tyler that's very nice of you!
I've edited my first post for the code. There's not much more to see than what I posted before because i'm already stucked with the first block...
About the image space.png, its height is 500px, its width is 960px (I mean on my design done in photoshop).
My problem is that I want each block to take the proportion of its background image so the background image appears normally and adapts to every resolution but it actually takes the text i'm writing in the html as a reference instead of the size of the background image... So its height is small... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Tyler. It's almost there, it's way more convincing than what I had but I don't know if it's the same on your screen but on mine the images are distorted, i mean the proportions of the 960x500 image are not applied. :/ what i have on my screen http://i.imgur.com/C1PnE8g.jpg

Comment: By proportions I mean the images' aspect ratio!

Comment: Another thing you can do is replace background-size: 100% 100% with background-size: cover; But you have to remember you're using percentages, do yes the aspect ratio will be off because the image will take up the contents of the parent div. So if your user for some reason decides to have a very skinny and long browser window, it's going to look strange.